# Why did Frederick VI claim the Haraldskær Woman was a Norwegian queen?

Tags: 19th-century, monarchy, denmark

[Frederick VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_VI_of_Denmark) was the last king of Denmark-Norway. During his reign a woman’s well preserved body was discovered in a peat bog, and Frederick claimed it was that of Queen Gunnhild.  Frederick’s wikipedia article states:

> After the discovery of the [Haraldskær Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haraldsk%C3%A6r_Woman) in a peat bog in
>   Jutland in the year 1835, Frederick VI ordered a royal interment in an
>   elaborately carved sarcophagus for the Iron Age mummy, decreeing it to
>   be the body of Queen Gunnhild. Later this identification proved
>   incorrect, but the action suited his political agenda at the time.[17]

Unfortunately that source link is dead, and the magazine it linked to has only a short article on the bog body. Frederick’s entry in Britannica states:

> Frederick, in 1834, set up four consultative provincial assemblies.
>   This action marked the beginning of parliamentary life in Denmark.

Those assemblies were formed only a year before the body was found. Based on other biographies it sounds like the monarchy was in decline at the time of his reign. If the country was trending towards a parliamentary system, did Frederick claim the body was a queen in an attempt to strengthen the monarchy’s image?  What were his political motivations for this claim?

Comment: The Wiki article on [Gunnhild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnhild,_Mother_of_Kings) has this explanation: "Because of the account of Gunnhild's murder contained in the Jomsviking Saga and other sources, the body was mistakenly identified as that of Gunnhild. Based upon the belief of her royal personage, King Frederick VI commanded an elaborate sarcophagus be carved to hold her body. "

Comment: @LarsBosteen Why does Frederick's article make it sound like he had some other motivation, beyond "royal duties?"

Comment: There seems to be a [copy of that article](https://www.scribd.com/document/144182750/Haraldsk%C3%A6r-Woman) on Scribd.  It doesn't say any more about Frederick's motivation though.  As to why the article is phrased that way, have you looked at the history on the Wikipedia article to see when that section was added, and whether there are any additional notations?

Comment: There's a biography of Frederick VI: *Engberg, Jens: [Den standhaftige tinsoldat : en biografi om Frederik 6](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=W3wiBQAAQBAJ&q=gunhild#v=onepage&q=gunhild&f=false)(2009)* but the pages which might elaborate on this aren't available for free viewing.

Comment: @sempaiscuba If I'm reading these annotations correctly, there was an issue in 2008 with a lack of references for the Haraldskaer Woman's page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Haraldsk%C3%A6r_Woman/GA1) but it doesn't mention Frederick.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Thanks I will search through that. I'm positive this answer can be found in a book once the libraries re-open! But for now I'll try to level up my google skills..

Comment: If you do find it, you can self-answer - I'd certainly like to know the answer. One other snippet I found is [this](http://tollundmanden.one/haraldskaer-womansider/?lang=en) "Probably because of the short distance to Jelling – only 10 km – and the name of the site, which means Gunhild’s Bog, it was believed that they had found Queen Gunhild of Norway...". Jelling was the old royal 'capital'.

Comment: @creative-username The paragraph was added by the Wikipedia editor [Covalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Covalent) on [25 August 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Frederick_VI_of_Denmark&oldid=71754567).  There is no explanation or citation for the _political agenda_ claimed in that paragraph.

Comment: There's an [article by Sanders 2009 in "Scandinavian Studies" behind a paywall](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40920836). It says that the bog body and the idea that it might be the ancient queen became a news story before king Frederik VI did anything. So it may have been out of his hands. Also, with the absolute monarchy under heavy criticism and having lost Norway recently (20 years before), a Norwegian queen who came to Denmark for marriage (to bring the countries together) and was murdered by the Danish king must have been a political issue. And actually perhaps not in Frederik VI's favor.